# Can't select specific child div

Tags: css

[image]

I came across a weird issue, I don't know what is going on here.
I'm building a react slide image and I want to give a special effect and therefor I want to select the div within the "each-slide" class and give it a color for instance red.

I have written a code in css file to select the specific div but this doesn't work.

Any idea of what is happening?
Below is the code of React and CSS

/************* React *************/

```
<SlideShow easing="ease">
        <div className="each-slide">
          <div>Slide-1</div>
        </div>
        <div className="each-slide">
          <div>Slide-2</div>
        </div>
        <div className="each-slide">
          <div>Slide-3</div>
        </div>
</SlideShow>
```

/************* CSS *************/

```
.each-slide > div {
    color: red;
}
```

Thank you in advanced, I appreciated!

Comment: What does the rendered HTML output from devtools look like? Like a screenshot if you can add that.

Comment: The issue is not css related, as you can see the css [works correctly](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lm2z3qc/).

Comment: Yup, css looks fine, but are those ` ` marks necessary?

Comment: Bjorn.B , just added a screenshot of the HTML output.

Comment: Neil W, ignore the batick marks, those are what I had to use to post my code, thnx

Comment: Guys, an observation, I just hard coded inline style and pass this to the desire div and it work, but that is not I want, it messes up my code :-(

Comment: React scopes your styles.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried to increase specificity?
See more details here:(https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

```
Slideshow.each-slide > div {
    color: red;
}
```